# How check that ALGORITHM=INPLACE is supported in MySql?

Tags: mysql, algorithm

MySql supports ALGORITHM=INPLACE starting with version 5.6.18 (as I understand), but is there a way to checkout this supporting via sql statement? E.g. what it needs to select to check that ALGORITHM=INPLACE is supported for particular MySql version or fork?